# apache2 and mysqldump causing massive load average spike

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mysql

I've got a problem that's causing me some headaches and I could use some ideas on how to investigate/fix it.

Setup:

- I'm running a Rails app (Apache2 w/ Passenger) on server A (Rails.A)
- I'm running the master DB on a dedicated DB server B (DB.B)
- I'm running a slave DB on server A (DB.A) with standard MySQL replication (just for backup purposes)
- Rails.A is reading/writing to DB.B

Problem:

- When running a mysqldump on DB.A, the load average on A skyrockets
  because Apache appears to spin off tonnes of processes.  This really
  doesn't make sense to me as DB.A isn't even used by Rails.A.  I can
  completely shutdown DB.A and Rails.A works just fine.
- I've even tried running the mysqldump with "ionice -c2 -n6", with no change.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I misread your question the first time, and didn't realize that Apache and the slave were on the same server.

I think that even with the nice settings on the dump, Apache is becoming resource starved. Whether it's being starved on io, memory or cpu, I don't know, you'll have to do some benchmarking (io is my guess though).

In any case, if you're still having trouble, I'd reask this question on ServerFault or get a mod to move it for you.

Comment: But I'm doing the dump on a slave, which reads replication updates from the master.  I've even stopped replication and the problem still persists.   Moreover, if I stop the slave DB all together then Apache does NOT block; which demonstrates that Apache is relying solely on the master server.